# What are all of the images sizes that you need for images on Android to make things look really good?

Tags: android

There are over 60 devices for Android.

What are all of the images sizes that you need for images on Android to make things look really good? From tablets to the smaller phones.

I know with Apple hardware this is very easy to figure out, but I am wondering about Android image sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android uses resource directory qualifiers to select the resources for a specific screen resolution (size, density, aspect ratio).

The idea is that you provide size and density specific resources for each of the different resolutions you want to support.

You can find some examples and the list of qualifiers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).